# How to use oraclize with Eris

Tags: oracles, eris-industries

I faced many problems in order to run oracles with Ethereum.
I'm thinking of using Eris and I need guide to use oracles with Eris.
I need example so i can get how it works.
is there any example?

Comment: The link doesn't include a guide, but it does have an official response from Eris suggesting you use their Gitter channel.